# Printar strings em ordem alfabética

Tags: c, string

Estou tentando fazer aqui pois o usuário fornece 3 nome no mínimo daí tenho que ordenar esses nomes em ordem alfabética, tinha tentado com `strcmp`, mas não entendi muito bem o conceito desse comando. Então usei o seguinte código:

```
char nm1[20], nm2[20], nm3[20], cont;
        char alf[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','w','y','z'};
        char alfb[26] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','X','W','Y','Z'};
        printf("Nome 1: ");
        scanf("%s", &nm1);
        printf("Nome 2: ");
        scanf("%s", &nm2);
        printf("Nome 3: ");
        scanf("%s", &nm3);

        for(cont = 0; cont < 26; cont++){
            if(nm1[0] == alf[cont]|| nm1[0] == alfb[cont])
                printf("- %s", nm1);
            if(nm2[0] == alf[cont]|| nm2[0] == alfb[cont])
                printf("- %s", nm2);
            if(nm3[0] == alf[cont]|| nm3[0] == alfb[cont])
                printf("- %s", nm3);    
        }
```

Ele compara a primeira letra de cada nome e printa se ela for igual a letra que eles está lendo do alfabeto. Mas assim ele só ordena pela primeira letra do nome, se o usuário digitar `ana, andre e adão` ele vai printar na mesma ordem e não na ordem alfabética correta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) recebe duas string para ser comparadas e vai ter 3 possíveis retornos:

- **menor que 0**: quando encontrar um carácter diferente nas strings e 
  esse carácter da primeira `String` for **menor** que da segunda `String`. (antes)
- **igual a 0**: quando são iguais.
- **maior que 0**: quando encontrar um carácter diferente nas strings e esse carácter da primeira `String` for **maior** que da segunda `String`. (depois)

Sugiro que você troque suas três variáveis para uma matriz de `char`, dessa forma ficará muito simples de ordenar.

```
char nm[3][20], aux[20];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   printf("\nNome %i: ", i+1);
   scanf("%s", nm[i]);
}


for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) { /* 3 = qtde de palavras */
   for (j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
      // verifica se tem que ser depois, se for troca de posição
      if (strcmp(nm[j - 1], nm[j]) > 0) {
         strcpy(aux, nm[j - 1]);
         strcpy(nm[j - 1], nm[j]);
         strcpy(nm[j], aux);
      }
   }
}

// só mostrar a matriz
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   printf("\n%s", nm[i]);
```

Lembre de dar *include* na `<string.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

O `strcmp()` devolve uma de tres hipoteses.

```
cmp = strcmp(n1, n2);
if (cmp == 0) /* n1 igual a n2 */;
if (cmp < 0) /* n1 menor que n2 */;
if (cmp > 0) /* n1 maior que n2 */;
```

Desde que te lembres disto, o uso do strcmp nao tem nada de especial.

Para comparares nomes, tens de ter converter tudo para minusculas (ou maiusculas) antes da comparacao: um ciclo com `tolower()` resolve esse problema.

Em pseudo codigo

```
obter nm1, nm2, nm3
converter nm1, nm2, e nm3 para minusculas,
      possivelmente com copia para nao perder a informacao original
trocar nm1 e nm2?
trocar nm2 e nm3?
trocer nm1 e nm2?
imprimir (as copias originais de) nm1, nm2, e nm3
```

Answer (score 2):

Vou postar uma possível resposta, é um algorítimo simples que faz a ordenação de palavras usando selectSort, `qtd` é a quantidade de palavras e `tam` é o tamanho das palavras.

```
# include<stdio.h>
const int qtd = 10;
const int tam = 30;
main()
{
    int i, j, x, menor;
    char a[qtd][tam], aux[qtd];
    for(i = 0; i < qtd; i++)
    {
        printf("Informe o %d° nome: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", a[i]);
    }
        for(i = 0; i < qtd - 1; i++)
        {
                x = 0;
                menor = i;
                for(j = i + 1; j < qtd; j++)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    while(a[menor][x] == a[j][x])
                    {
                            x++;
                    } 
                    if(a[menor][x] > a[j][x])
                    {
                         menor = j;
                    }
                }
                if(menor != i)
                {
                        strcpy(aux, a[menor]);
                        strcpy(a[menor], a[i]);
                        strcpy(a[i], aux);
                }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < qtd; i++)
        {
                printf("%s%c", a[i], 10);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Ordenar vetor alfabeticamente*/

# include <stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

int main (){

char nome[3][100], copia[100];

int i, j;

/* A variável nome armazena 3 nomes com até 100 caracteres.

A variável copia é apenas uma auxiliar que recebe 100 caracteres
*/

//Entrada dos nomes

for ( i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
   printf ( "Informe o nome: " );
   gets ( nome[i] );
}

//A troca alfabeticamente

for ( i = 0; i < (3-1) ; i ++ ) 
   for( j = i + 1; j < 3; j ++ )

/* strcmp 
     retorna = 0, caso a = b
     retorna > 0, caso a > b
     retorna < 0, caso a < b
*/

      if ( strcmp( nome[i], nome[j] ) > 0 ){
/* strcpy
       copia de string 
       strcpy ( VarRecebe, VarEntrega )
*/
          strcpy ( copia, nome[i] );
         strcpy( nome[i], nome[j] );
         strvpy( nome[j], copia) ;
}


/* Apresentação do vetor

Essa eu deixo para que finalizes, ou seja para que a gente não faça tudo. 
Acredito que sabes a lógica para apresentar um determinado vetor, portanto só tens de colocá-la abaixo . 

NB: Considerando que o vetor é nome[] e não nome[][]
*/


}
}
```