# Listagem por nome em uma struct

Tags: c

Boa tarde.
Estou com esse empecilho num trabalho que estou fazendo. 
O trabalho consiste em: criar um sistema de cadastro de alunos, onde o usuário registra o nome e o registro do aluno. 
Durante a listagem dos dados, deve ser ordenado os nomes em ordem alfabética. A parte de cadastro e de listagem está ok. apenas a ordenação que não estou conseguindo fazer.

Eis o código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct aluno{
int ra;
char nome[20];
struct aluno *anterior;
struct aluno *ant;
int aux;

   };

 void cadastraaluno();
 void listaaluno();
 struct aluno *al=NULL, *ant=NULL;
 struct aluno aux;

main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
int opcao;

do{ // execute o codigo...
system("cls");  
printf("============== SISTEMA CADASTRO DE ALUNOS ==============\n\n");
printf("\n 1- Cadastrar");
printf("\n 2- Listar");
printf("\n 3- Sair\n");
printf("\n Qual opção? ");
scanf("%d",&opcao);

switch(opcao)
    {// inicio switch

        case 1:{

        cadastraaluno();
        break;
        }
        case 2:{
            listaaluno();

            break;
        }

        case 3:{
            printf("Saindo...");
            break;
        }

            default:{
                printf("opção inválida.");
        }

    }//end switch

        getch();
        }while(opcao!=3); // 
        getch();

        }
void cadastraaluno(){

al=(struct aluno*) malloc(sizeof(struct aluno));
printf("RA:");
scanf("%d",&(*al).ra);
fflush(stdin);
printf("NOME:");
gets((*al).nome);
(*al).anterior=ant;
ant=al; 
}


void listaaluno(){
printf("\n Foram cadastrados os seguintes dados: \n\n");

while((*al).anterior !=NULL){ // enquanto registro anterior não for nulo.
    printf("\n RA: %d",(*al).ra);
    printf("\n NOME: %s\n",(*al).nome);
    al=(*al).anterior;  

     aux=*ant;
     *ant=*al;
      *al=*ant;

} // termino while

printf("\n RA: %d",(*al).ra);
printf("\n NOME: %s",(*al).nome);

getch();    

}
```

A listagem funciona ok. porém ela necessita ser em ordem alfabética. alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Existe uma lib que já faz isso para você em cpp. Ela organiza seus dados. Mas olha esse artigo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72494/printar-strings-em-ordem-alfab%C3%A9tica
Com certeza vai te ajudar!

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda! a lib que você diz seria a string.h?

Answer (score 0):

você pode tentar utilizar o comando `strcmp(string1, string2)` pra comparar duas strings e tentar ordenar com um auxiliar de ponteiro